# Get Placeholder Info

Tags: c++, winapi

```
HANDLE hfile = ??
int size = sizeof(CF_PLACEHOLDER_STANDARD_INFO) + fileIdentity_MaxLength;
CF_PLACEHOLDER_STANDARD_INFO* standard_info = (CF_PLACEHOLDER_STANDARD_INFO*)new BYTE[size];
DWORD returnlength(0);
HRESULT result = CfGetPlaceholderInfo(
     hfile, 
     CF_PLACEHOLDER_INFO_STANDARD, 
     standard_info, 
     size, 
     &returnlength);
```

That file is placeholder on SyncRoot (like "file on-demand" of onedrive)
I try to get placeholder info but that required file handle. Then i try `CreateFile` but it need download file.  Then how i can get file handle without download? or easy solution for get PlaceholderInfo from file?
Thank.

Comment: Have you checked the MSDN for examples?

Comment: examples not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use createfile like this:

```
CreateFile( filepath, 0, FILE_WRITE_DATA | FILE_READ_DATA, nullptr,
                                OPEN_EXISTING,
                                FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                                nullptr )
```

Answer (score 0):

`CfGetPlaceholderInfo()` (and [other CfApi functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfapi/)) expects a `HANDLE` from [`CfOpenFileWithOplock()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfapi/nf-cfapi-cfopenfilewithoplock). See [Cloud Filter API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/_cloudapi/) on MSDN for more details.

Comment: It download file too (because it trigger CF_CALLBACK_TYPE_FETCH_DATA)